# How can I run xcode after installation using "darling"?

Tags: xubuntu

I had installed darling their official documentation.

```bash
sudo apt install cmake clang bison flex libfuse-dev libudev-dev pkg-config libc6-dev-i386 \
gcc-multilib libcairo2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libtiff5-dev \
libfreetype6-dev git git-lfs libelf-dev libxml2-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
libbsd-dev libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev libgif-dev libavutil-dev libpulse-dev \
libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libswresample-dev libdbus-1-dev libxkbfile-dev \
libssl-dev python2
git clone --recursive https://github.com/darlinghq/darling.git
git lfs install
git pull
git submodule init
git submodule update
# Move into the cloned sources
cd darling

# Make a build directory
mkdir build && cd build

# Configure the build
cmake ..

# Build and install Darling
make
sudo make install
```

To install xcode I followed [their](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/xcode) guide.

```bash
darling shell
```

Then darling start in the terminal. Then I executed following script to install Xcode

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

After the installation, I can't find it in start menu. I thought, I used darling so it won't be there. But I can't find any way to run it from darling terminal also. How do I start it?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Looks like darling shell is only for CLI programs. but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @devnullΨ I have read in some documentation that xcode doesn't have GUI for Linux (when we install xcode using darling there's no GUI).

Comment: @Istiak really? I did not even know that xcode can be used as CLI program